# Two dual booted ubuntus

Tags: boot, dual-boot

So, because I had to reinstall Ubuntu 20.04 on my IBM Lenovo T460s laptop due to some important files being deleted in the previous one, I had incorrectly installed Ubuntu on my laptop and due to this I now have two Ubuntu's; one with deleted important files and one that's being used by me all the time, how do I make it so that there is only one Ubuntu, so I don't have to choose via the dual/multibooter.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 2 Ubuntu installations, they are each on a different partition.
Use **gparted** to format the partition with broken Ubuntu.
Next mount the empty partition to /mnt in order to use the space.
You might also need to update the grub also to remove the entries.

```
sudo update-grub   # from a terminal
```

Answer (score 0):

**Go To Applications Menu On Ubuntu 20.04 And Search For An App Called Disks, Click it, Then Format The Ubuntu You Don Not Need Or Want...
Open Terminal And Type The Following Command Once Partition Is Formatted :**

```
sudo update-grub
```